# What does で踏める mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, nuances, readings, reading-comprehension

[image]

I'm a bit stumbled on the meaning of で踏めるな here.

So the character sister's gets home and she's shocked her brother brought a friend.  Then the brother introduces the friend and the sister goes "nice to meet you, is the curry good?" and they answer "we still haven't eaten yet"

After that the mother adds

"で踏めるな" The part before the で are the protagonist and the brother's names.

to which the sister replies

踏んでどうする

The protagonist too seems to be confused to I guess it may be a weird meaning?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150357/discussion-on-question-by-kawase-k-what-does--mean-in-this-sentence); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Is this from a published manga? If so, what is the title?

Comment: @YusukeMatsubara 画像検索すると出ますが[これ](https://www.harta.jp/articles/001020.html)です。唐突に言われて意味が分からず困惑する表現だということ自体が「文脈」ですね…。

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly a peculiar way of saying [韻を踏む](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%9F%BB%E3%82%92%E8%B8%8F%E3%82%80) (**a**d**a**ch**i**-**a**t**a**m**i**).

> 熱海と足立で(韻を)踏めるな。
> You can make a rhyme with Atami and Adachi.

This phrase is usually not contracted to 踏む, but a certain type of people (e.g., a musician) might just say 踏む as jargon.

Comment: Oh that would make sense. And I see the な is not imperative then. What do you make of でどうする　 then here?

Comment: @Kawase_K ～てどうする is a way of saying "So what?" or "What for?". BTW do you know her job? Is she an artist or something?

Comment: I don't think it's ever said at this point. And after that it's not cleared up (as far as this chapter goes)